# Why does this limit for $\sin$ work this way?

Tags: calculus

What is the proof/logic behind this statement?  For instance, I see people simplifying the following statement like so:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin (cx)}{x} = c\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin (cx)}{cx} = c$$

But I am not sure how this is supposed to simplify into the limit at $0$ being equal to $c$?

EDIT: I'm sorry about that.  I have fixed the question now.  I don't understand how $$c\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin (cx)}{cx} = c$$

Comment: What you wrote makes no sense. What do you mean by $0\Rightarrow c$?

Comment: Do not use implications ($\Rightarrow$) to mean equalities ($=$). In your first displayed line, the $\Rightarrow$ should be $=$.

Comment: You are supposed to know already that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.  Do you remember that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $y = cx \ $ then
$$c \lim_{x\to 0}{\sin(cx)\over cx} = c \lim_{y\to 0}{\sin(y)\over y} = c\cdot 1 = c.$$

Comment: And this is because, for nonzero $c$, $x\rightarrow 0$ if and only if $cx\rightarrow 0$ (stated for benefit of OP).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use L'Hospital's rule directly on this, assuming you've covered that. Since plugging in 0 for x gets you the form $\frac 0 0$,  you take the limit of the derivative of the top over the derivative of the bottom: $lim_{x\to 0}\frac {c \cos x} 1=c$